# Mux telemetry data into a MPEG-ts file using gstreamer

Tags: c, gstreamer, subtitle, telemetry, transport-stream

I recently starting using Gstreamer and I have succeeded in muxing an audio stream and 2 camera streams into a MPEG-TS file using the mpegtsmux and now want to inject telemetry data from an accelerometer into the data stream. I was thinking by using teletext to do that, which is supported by the mpegtsmux and then use the appsrc to inject the data into the pipeline. Does anyone succeeded in doing this before, I can't seem to find any examples with injecting teletext into a data stream.

Answer (score 0):

How about to use the sound channel without compression?

Answer (score 0):

Use the application/x-teletext caps to create pad to the mux..

I'm yet to able successfully do it. If you have, I'd be interested on how you used appsrc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).